# Unable to copy GridView inside a div via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to copy the div's content to another div on the click of image. The div contains gridview which I want to copy to another div. When I click on the image it populate gridview via objectdatasource.

I tried the following code:

```
var innerHtml = $("#innerGrids")[0].innerHTML;
$("#" + divname).html(innerHtml);
```

This code copy grid's html inside div but without the data. I think the problem is as soon as I click, it copy the contents but does not wait for data to load in grid. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @ SiD after grid load call your method

Comment: @ozil how do I know objectdatasource loaded data into grid on client side?

Comment: Check length of gridview on client side as Gridview is rendered as table you can check length of table rows if rows > 1 than call your method.